# Filter List entries

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a list with 3 entries -

```
public class entry
{
    string name;
    string age;
    string likes;    
}

List<entry> groupEntry = new List<entry>();
```

Where -

```
groupEntry[0].name = "john";
groupEntry[0].age= "26";
groupEntry[0].likes= "cats";

groupEntry[1].name = "john";
groupEntry[1].age= "26";
groupEntry[1].likes= "dogs";

groupEntry[2].name = "matt";
groupEntry[2].age= "32";
groupEntry[2].likes= "frogs";
```

What i am trying to do is make a new list, whereby name is a unique identifier, and just create one entry per name however add the likes together into on string array with the resulting list looking like -

```
public class filteredEntry
{
    string name;
    string age;
    List<string> likes;    
}

List<filteredEntry> filteredGroupEntry = new List<filteredEntry>();

filteredGroupEntry [0].name = "john";
filteredGroupEntry [0].age= "26";
filteredGroupEntry [0].likes= ["cats", "dogs"];

filteredGroupEntry [1].name = "matt";
filteredGroupEntry [1].age= "32";
filteredGroupEntry [1].likes= "frogs";
```

My thoughts were to do a foreach with `groupEntry` and each time entry[i].name changes make a new record in `filteredGroupEntry` however could not get this to work with a new array for `likes`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: That would require a new class since you want a `List<string>` instead of a `string`.

Comment: Your filtered list cannot be of type `List<entry>` as the dob/likes field is a string, but you want to have an array of strings..

Comment: have updated accordingly sorry I missed that part out

Comment: if you don't want to change your design you can store jobs in on string with a separator like `|`... and have string like `"cats|dogs"`. then only implement a method to get array of jobs like this. `string[] GetJobs => jobs.Split('|');`

Comment: Can you decide if it's 'likes' or 'dob'? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to make the fields in your `entry` class `public`. Until now your code won't compile.

Second is that `likes` is already a `string` so you cannot transform it into an array, but what you could do is just to concatenate all the stuff that a person likes and separate them with a `,`. So you would group by name and take all `likes` values in one string. This code takes only the first `age` value (assuming that it is always the same John with the same age May be not the smartest solution.

```
List<entry> filteredList = groupEntry.GroupBy(x => x.name)
        .Select(x => new entry
        {
            name = x.First().name,
            age = x.First().age,
            likes = String.Join(", ", x.Select(l=>l.likes))
        }).ToList();
```

Later on when you want to separate the `like` thingies again you could split by `,` like this:

```
string [] allOneLikes = filteredList[0].likes.Split(',');
```

**EDIT:**

I just saw that you edited your post and added the `filteredEntry` class.
This changes the situation of course. So you could then use this class in the `Select` statement:

```
List<filteredEntry> filteredList = groupEntry.GroupBy(x => x.name)
        .Select(x => new filteredEntry
        {
            name = x.First().name,
            age = x.First().age,
            likes = x.Select(l=>l.likes).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *grouping by* via *Linq*:

```
List<filteredEntry> filteredGroupEntry = groupEntry
  .GroupBy(entry => new { // grouping by name + age
     name = entry.name,
     age = entry.age})
  .Select(chunk => new filteredEntry() { 
     name = chunk.Key.name,
     age = chunk.Key.age, 
     // collapse all likes into list
     likes = chunk.Select(entry => entry.likes).ToList()})
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Excellent answer Dmitry however Mong Zhu got there just before you.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I salute once again. Especially of the grouping by **name && age** !